# Ubuntu specific questions

Tags: discussion, migration, ubuntu

[This has already been discussed](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389/migrate-ubuntu-specific-questions-to-askubuntu), but I think it warrants reconsideration.

[Jeff's answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/391/6761), in particular:

> So I'd only migrate questions where the question is extremely and unavoidably Ubuntu-centric, and cannot be generalized to other *nixes in any meaningful way.

After [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315453/a-question-about-bash-profile) was migrated and looking at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81933/how-can-i-set-the-tty-font-size-manually-in-lubuntu)<sup>1</sup>, I realized that it is becoming increasingly difficult to keep track of where Ubuntu has deviated from other *nixes in general, and Debian specifically. And this trend seems likely to only accelerate.

Should the cognitive overhead of trying to keep track of those changes be carried here, or should *buntu questions just be migrated across to where the real depth of expertise with that family of distros resides?

And could we please have a radio button for it on the close page, as per SO?

---

<sup>1. Which I got wrong.</sup>

<sup>**Note** This question could also be a thinly veiled lament for my failing powers of memory—or lack of diligence in keeping track of Ubuntu's innovation, either option definitely holds...</sup>

Comment: re: note, it depends on how you define innovation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have trouble telling the difference too these days, but the burden of ensuring a question should be migrated is normally on the source site. I think you're suggesting we should migrate all posts that seem like they might be Ubuntu-specific, and let them deal with figuring out if that's actually true or not, which doesn't seem particularly fair to them and is bad for us if we're losing a bunch of questions that are actually on-topic here. As for adding a migration path, that site more than any other I think would be risky, because we get an awful lot of "belongs on Ask Ubuntu" flags because the asker happens to be using Ubuntu, even if the question has nothing to do with Ubuntu specifically; I think we'd end up migrating a lot of generic Linux posts over there. In the last 90 days we only sent them 5 posts (and received 6), so it doesn't seem like there's a high demand for a migration path between the sites

Comment: I agree in principle; but I think--given their choices about departing from using *nix standard approaches--the onus should be on them (they have the knowledge), and I haven't seen much in the way of questions that we would actually regret losing, unless volume is a consideration.

Comment: But there should be a way to flag [questions like this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79462/41104) that are obviously ubuntu(in-any-flavor)-specific questions