# How to mark something that is off topic including for Meta and StackOveflow?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

If I review a question and want to close it as off topic, I run into a dead end:

For example, the question is about Android, with no explicit or implicit relation to Unix or Linux.

There is no problem, I have to mark it as plain "off topic" or as "off topic but belongs to Android". All is perfectly fine until I run into the list of sites I may indicate it belongs to. There are only two sites listed, and there is no "others" field.

What should I do at that point?
Why is it like that?

Comment: Very similar to your previous question, https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5484/the-migration-target-askubuntu-should-be-available, but I think https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5483/why-can-we-not-vote-to-migrate-a-question-to-superuser-com has most of what I might say in response to this question. Why not use the custom close reason ("Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)")

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, similar. (To be clear, I'm not 'complaing', but rather write down a UI problem.) Here, I did not intend to migrate it, and did not use an item for migration. I went a straight path that suddenly ended. Yes, I went back out and used the free form comment. I looked for a plain "off topic" first. Often, it's not clear whether/which suitable site exists, or the question is off topic beyond reclaim. If back and "other" is the official way, that's an answer. (There was the minor problem that the field enforced a nontrivial length, while "Android" or "to Android" would fit)

Comment: So you're suggesting there should be a free-form option within the "Migration" page to let people specify where it should go that raises a flag, so they don't need to back out and choose the "Other" option?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek No, the list did not contain Migration. And the free text in the "other" field ended up as comment. I'm not sure which review queue it was.

Comment: Android uses the Linux kernel and a lot of Linux tools. Effectively, it is an embedded Linux. Of course it has nothing to do with LSB and to any relevant Linux standard, but it is still a Linux. The Android SE is declarated only for user-level questions. They redirect programming questions to here or to the SO. I think, Android should be mostly ontopic (well, maybe "how to use X app" questions should go to the Android SE, but that is all).

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica I did not keep my example, but remember it mentioned Android in a high level UI context. Though I'm aware of the layering (Android running on a Java Virtual Machine, which runs on Linux, which runs something surprisingly small and quick.), you reminded me of what the user means when he says Android. He basically means the whole software stack. If I use term, I normally mean the Android UI and framework, with or without the JWM. But without Linux. I think the Linux is pretty much complete, except that the common commands are missing, which can be fixed by a single file.